# Stochastic delay differential equation

Tags: stochastic-processes

$$dX(t)=F(t, X(t), X(t − τ ))dt + G(t, X(t), X(t − τ ))dW(t)$$
In the stochastic delay differential equation(SDDE) given above, can we assume that the delayed time $τ$ is stochastic process? If so, is there any method of finding $F$, $G$?